# What are the limits of leathery wings?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, alternate-reality, dinosaurs, wings

I want to experiment with alternate realities where pterosaurs continued to evolve or where Ambopteryx was more of a success, but there's a problem. What can't leathery wings do? Are they waterproof? Could such wings shrink to allow swimming or would they become like the fins of rays? I know bats can swim, but it's more of a glorified doggy paddle.

Comment: :-) Your skin is just another kind of leather. Do you consider it waterproof?

Comment: Leathery wings are basically water-proof, but any wing made for Air is very awkward in water. Exceptions are possible though, look at the Puffin. Leathery wings will expose the creature to the thermal shock of the water much more than feathers, though.

Comment: Because of the blood flow as opposed to deattachable feathers. Good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to infer how pterosaurs swam. But given that many species adapted to feed on marine fish and squid, they were probably able to dive in order to catch their prey. They probably did it much in the same way that some marine birds do.

From the wiki on [Rhamphorhynchus:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhamphorhynchus)

> Though Rhamphorhynchus is often depicted as an aerial piscivore, recent evidence suggests that, much like most modern aquatic birds, it probably foraged while swimming. Like several pteranodontians it has hatchet-shaped deltopectoral crests, a short torso and short legs, all features associated with water based launching in pterosaurs. Its feet are broad and large, being useful for propulsion, and the predicted floating position is adequate by pterosaur standards. The animal's ability to swim may account for the genus' generally excellent fossil record, being in a position where preservation would be much easier.

When I think about what those wings **can't** do, I wonder about what kinds of things you can only achieve with feathers. Owls are able to fly so silently because their wing feather act as mufflers. Part of a hawk's agility comes from the way they can move their tail feathers - a pterosaur's tail just can't match that. A leathery wing would hardly be colorful like that of a bird of paradise. And I find it unlikely that a miniature pterosaur would flap its wings as fast as a humming bird.

Comment: "And a leathery wing would hardly be colorful like that of a bird of paradise."
Nature knows plenty of bright colorful skin pigmentations though. Mandrils are the most obvious example.